# Snowflake Sample data set

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I unable to create objects (views, file format, stage etc.. ) in a shared sample database (SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA).

Kindly let me know, what is the possible way to get access the data?

Regards,
DB

Answer (score 0):

The SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DAT database contains a schema for each data set, with the sample data stored in the tables in each schema. **You can execute queries on the tables in these databases just as you would any other databases in your account**.

The database and schemas do not utilize any data storage so they do not incur storage charges for your account.
however, just as with other databases, **executing queries requires a running, current warehouse for your session, which consumes credits**.

You can refer to snowflake documentation: DOCS » USING SNOWFLAKE » SAMPLE DATASETS.

Hope this helps answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Shared databases are read-only. Users in a consumer account can view/query data, but cannot insert or update data, or create any objects in the database. This is why you can not create any objects on the shared database (SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-share-consumers.html#general-limitations-for-shared-databases

You can query the data in shared database like any other database.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-share-consumers.html#querying-a-shared-database